# how to print [0][0] as 001 using C# in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to know that how to print 0 as 000 and 1 as 001 in C# and so on.

I tried using `dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();` but it doesn't seem to work

Can anyone please suggest any method

Comment: Try the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: `but it doesn't seem to work` What does it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending of `dt.Rows[0][0]` type, you can simply write:

```
dt.Rows[0][0].ToString("000");
```

Perhaps you need to cast, for example if an `int` is presented as an `object`:

```
((int)dt.Rows[0][0]).ToString("000");
```

[ToString(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.single.tostring?#System_Single_ToString_System_String_)